# Can I save the changed initial values to a spring file?

Tags: java, spring, initialization

- An application takes its initial values from Spring file.
- A user, using configuration, changes some initial values.
- Can the application save the new initial values back to the Spring file, to reuse them again at the next start?

Of course, I can work with the file by means of usual io functions, but what about features of the Spring itself?

**Edit:** 
Also, I can use properties, databases and many other things. But I am talking about Spring. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can read your configuration (property) values from a database, instead of spring file, and the application can save the new values if its changed.
See this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28893/Loading-Application-Properties-from-a-Database)

Comment: Thank you, but could you answer the question, please? Is it possible? or not?

Comment: As far I know, you cannot edit the spring config files in runtime, also I think its not a good practice to change the initial values u configured. If you want to change it, change either in seperate property files or store it in database so that it will be picked up next time when u restart the server.

Comment: Why it is a bad practice?

Comment: Its because you dont know who changed it, why it was changed and what was the original value configured. If you do the change externally in the database you can record all the above information.

Comment: And how could something impossible be a bad, or *some*, practice?

Comment: It is for a programmer to organize it properly. Not a problem at all.

Comment: And to collect initials from not only different sources, but different KINDS of sources is really a bad practice.

Comment: Nothing to impossible, you could extend spring api and make it update your spring file. If someone is modifing your application spring i think its better to record it because you can know why it was modified in the first place and the reason it was modified. If you override ur spring file then how do you know the original value if you need to know.

Comment: I would simply divide the initiation info into base part - not for changing and volatile part - for changing by user through configuration... So, it is NOT possible, I have to extend spring API to use it. And is this part extendable? Could you make an answer of it?

Comment: The complete spring framework is open source in git https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework

Comment: So, it is NOT possible, I have to extend spring API to use it. Could you make an answer of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer for read values from property file. When values are changed, you can rewrite properties file, and new values will be applied during new start.
But better store such values in database.

Comment: Yes, I use properties and I love them, too. But I am talking about Spring now. Yes or not?

Comment: BTW, IMHO, properties are MUCH more convenient than DB for the initial values. Properties can be hand edited.

Comment: Spring can read properties in Spring context with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, please search example. When user changed properties, you can rewrite this property file by yours code. I don't now is Spring has such functionality.